# When is the lower variation of a class of sets negative?

Tags: measure-theory

I am going through Munroe's Book on measure theory . In the second chapter , which is about the general Measure theory , he introduces the concept of Lower Variations and upper variations .

It mentions the following  :

if $ \sigma $ is additive , then for each $ E $ which belongs to $ \alpha $ , which is the domain of $ \sigma $ , the upper variation , $ V $ ,is defined as the $\  \sup $ $\ { \sigma(A)}$ for $\ A $  in $ \alpha $ and $\ A  $ contained in $ E $ and similarly the lower variation , $ v $is defined as   $\  \inf $ $\ { \sigma(A)}$ .

As $\ \varnothing $ is contained in $ \ E $ and also in domain $ \alpha $ it is written that it implies  that

$V $ $\ \geq $ $ 0 $ $\ \geq $ $\ v $ .

In what situation , can the lower variation be negative ? If I understand properly then it suggests there are sets which constitute $ \varnothing $ , but I am unable to make sense of it .

How to explain negative lower variation ?

EDIT :  Maybe , I might gain some understanding by examples of situations in which the function $\ \sigma $ was permitted to assume negative values. So I should cover them as well in case , my understanding is not wrong about negative value of $\ \sigma $ suggesting sets which constitute $\ \varnothing $ . So what are the examples of situations which motivate negative value of $\ \sigma $ ?

Comment: You can use `\emptyset` ($\emptyset$) or `\varnothing` ($\varnothing$) to represent the emptyset. Please don't use the greek letter $\phi$, as that is very confusing for your readers.

Answer (score 1):

$\sigma(A) < \sigma(B)$ does not mean $A \subset B$. They can be entirely unrelated sets.

The thing is, $\sigma$ is not a required to be a measure. I.e., it can be negative. For example
$$A \mapsto \int_A \sin x\,dx$$

defines an additive set function which takes on negative values for some sets.

The statement about the lower variation being $ \le 0$ follows because $v$ is the infimum over all measurable subsets of $E$. $\varnothing$ is a measurable subset of $E$, so $v \le \sigma(\varnothing)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I got clarity on this now.